# question on float type

Tags: c#, types, c#-2.0

How can I detect an value is 4 bytes float type or 8 byte float type or not both in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "value"? What do you mean by "value is 4 bytes ... or 8 byte"?

Comment: should be variable. not value. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(float))
    // 4-byte float
else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(double))
    // 8-byte float
else
    // other
```

Alternatively, this should do the same thing:

```
if (obj is float)
    // 4-byte float
else if (obj is double)
    // 8-byte float
else
    // other
```

Comment: Not sure this is what the OP is after.

Comment: I couldn't think of any other reasonable meaning to the question.

Answer (score 4):

`float` in C# is always an alias for `System.Single`, which is always a 4 byte floating point value.

`double` in C# is always an alias for `System.Double`, which is an 8 byte floating point value.

If you are dealing with a `float` value, in C#, it is always 4 bytes.  This is not platform dependent, but rather guaranteed by the C# specification.

The C# spec, section 1.3 (Types and variables) states this explicitly:

> The two floating point types, float and double, are represented using the 32-bit single-precision and 64-bit double-precision IEEE 754 formats.

Answer (score 1):

To see it your variable is a float or not, use the following code

```
if( myVariable is float ){
  ...
}
```

To see the actual size of float if that is what you need:

```
int length = sizeof(float);
```

You cannot use `sizeof(myVariable)`, so you have to use both of the two approaches above.